# My EF Core console application with Database1.mdf file doesn't work when I try it in my Azure VM

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2019.
- Entity Framework Core 3.17
- SQL Server database file
- Azure Virtual Machine  Win 10 Pro

I have an Entity Framework Core console app that talks to a `Database1.mdf` SQL Server database file that also resides in my solution. All this is checked in my Azure Repo. This works on my local machine. Here is the [article link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx).

When I pull this down in my Azure VM (same specs) and try to run it I get the following error. I do have both files (`.mdf` and `.ldf`) set to `Copy Always` to Output in properties.

Any ideas?

Here's my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": 
{
    "Storage": "Server=(local);AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;Database=Database1;Integrated Security=True;"
}
```

Error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never use "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database1.mdf;" when database is already attached to the server.  Remove.  You already have Server set.  Integrated Security=True is using the windows login account for current user and the database must also allow the same user or group the user belongs to.

Comment: If I delete solution folder on my local machine and download again it still continues to work properly even with connection string shown above. Seems like a permission issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: AttachDbFilename asks the SQL Instance to attach the database file, which it requires filesystem permissions to do.  Better to attach the database permanently to the instance, 
 by copying it into the SQL Server's data directory, attach it with SSMS, and just connect to it.

Comment: If the file is already attached to the database the database owns the file and you do not have permission to modify the database.  Deleting removed the file from the server which gives you permission.  The is why you never us AttachDbFilename when the file is already attached.